# Responsive Web Design not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive web site by doing mobile first. When I start adding my media query (min-width), I toggle the inspect element on Google to see if it is responsive and it is not.

I choose different mobile phones and iPads and everything is totally different from scaling the browser window smaller and larger.

Should I be worried about the inspect element? I don't want put out a website that is not responsive. Any ideas?

I have tried media query at min-width 768, 998, 1200, and when i go choose different phone option it is not responsive.

Comment: Make sure to have a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` tag in the `<head>` of your document ^^

Comment: Please include a simplified version of your code for reference, that will help us understand and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this code inside of  `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It ensures that your website display correctly in browser (when in 'mobile view' or in smarphones, for example).